# C# Defined Delegate As Function , How To Convert It In VB.NET

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

I have this class , define delegate as function as fellow

```
<br />

using System;<br />
using System.Collections.Generic;<br />
using System.Linq;<br />
using System.Text;<br />
using System.ComponentModel;<br />
using System.Collections;<br /><br />
namespace ClassLibrary1<br />
{<br />
    public delegate bool DrillDownHandler(IComponent control);<br />
    public delegate void ComponentLoadedHandler(IComponent control);

        public interface interface1
    {
        event DrillDownHandler DrillDown;
        event ComponentLoadedHandler ComponentLoaded;
    }


    public class Class1 : interface1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            DrillDown += new DrillDownHandler(DrillDownDefault);
        }

        private ArrayList drillList = new ArrayList();
        public event DrillDownHandler DrillDown
        {
            add
            {
                drillList.Add(value);
            }
            remove
            {
                drillList.Remove(value);
            }
        }
        public event ComponentLoadedHandler ComponentLoaded;

        private bool DrillDownDefault(IComponent control)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

When convert to VB.Net the following code we get ,,, but not work

```
<br /><br />
Imports System<br />
Imports System.Collections.Generic<br />
Imports System.Linq<br />
Imports System.Text<br />
Imports System.ComponentModel<br />
Imports System.Collections<br />
<br />
Namespace ClassLibrary1<br />
    Public Delegate Function DrillDownHandler(control As IComponent) As Boolean<br />
    Public Delegate Sub ComponentLoadedHandler(control As IComponent)<br />


    Public Interface interface1
        Event DrillDown As DrillDownHandler
        Event ComponentLoaded As ComponentLoadedHandler
    End Interface


    Public Class Class1
        Inherits interface1
        Public Sub New()
            DrillDown += New DrillDownHandler(DrillDownDefault)
        End Sub

        Private drillList As New ArrayList()
        Public Custom Event DrillDown As DrillDownHandler
            AddHandler(ByVal value As DrillDownHandler)
                drillList.Add(value)
            End AddHandler
            RemoveHandler(ByVal value As DrillDownHandler)
                drillList.Remove(value)
            End RemoveHandler
        End Event
        Public Event ComponentLoaded As ComponentLoadedHandler

        Private Function DrillDownDefault(control As IComponent) As Boolean
            Return False
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Any one can help

Comment: You either are going to have to learn how to program in vb.net code or find a much better converter.  This one did a particularly crappy job.  SO is not a translation service.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.Net Event can not be declared with a Delegate that has a return type. Only Event with Sub 'Delegate' is possible. Use a 'Sub' delegate with a 'ByRef' parameter instead.

```
Public Delegate Sub DrillDownHandler(control As IComponent, ByRef bReturnVal As Boolean)
```

For more information visit http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vblanguage/thread/f1141545-6ef5-49df-8c16-ad27ee41a3bc

Hope It should work.